# Python webservise http response text json to dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, httpresponse

How to have a http response JSON to Pandas DataFrame

```
 r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
 r.text
```

> '{\n  "Process": "[1, 1]"\n}\n'

How to take this "Process": "[1, 1]" from the r.text to a DataFrame with 'Process' as colunm name and 1,1 as valuess in each row. In this case , we can expect output dataFrame with one Column 'Process' and 2 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `ast` and `json.loads`

```
import ast
import json

x  = {k: ast.literal_eval(v) for k,v in json.loads(s).items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```